# How do I decompress an NSString I have that was compressed with zlib

Tags: objective-c, zlib, compression

I have an `NSString` (e.g. `eNoLycgsVgChvILSEoWS1IoSPQBFZgb4`) that I get from a web server that is just a normal string compressed using `zlib`. How do I decompress this in Objective-C? I've found some libraries but they only accept full files, not a simple string.

Comment: What do you mean by "compressed"? The string in question isn't binary compressed since it's using ASCII characters, but it doesn't look like Base64 either. What GLib method was used to produce the example you give and what was the original input string?

Comment: @AndrewHodgkinson Here's an example website showing it: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/compress/ you can input the text to deflate or inflate existing text. This website properly decompresses the text I receive from the server's API so I guess I'm just curious how I would do it locally

Comment: @AndrewHodgkinson Similarly this site will do the same with deflate http://www.txtwizard.net/compression

Comment: The example data is a zlib (not "glib") stream encoded in Base64. It decompresses to `This is input text.`.

Comment: For anyone reading this and being confused about "glib" references, the original question mistyped "zlib" and instead said "glib". It looks like the O.P. has updated their question since and fixed it, which makes the above few comments confusing, but at the same time makes it much more valuable for long term archives and Google results. Kudos! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK based on the above it seems you didn't really know what the format is - but seems that it's ZLib `deflate`, Base64 encoded. Cribbing shamelessly off other StackOverflow answers, here's a chunk of code that'll decompress your data:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <zlib.h>

int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSLog( @"Starting..." );

        NSString      * base64String     = @"eJwLycgsVgChvILSEoWS1IoSPQBFZgb4";
        NSData        * compressedData   = [ [ NSData alloc ] initWithBase64EncodedString: base64String options: 0 ];
        NSUInteger      full_length      = [ compressedData length ];
        NSUInteger      half_length      = [ compressedData length ] / 2;
        NSMutableData * decompressedData = [ NSMutableData dataWithLength: full_length + half_length ];
        BOOL            done             = NO;
        int             status;
        z_stream        strm;

        strm.next_in   = ( Bytef * )[ compressedData bytes  ];
        strm.avail_in  = ( unsigned int ) full_length;
        strm.total_out = 0;
        strm.zalloc    = Z_NULL;
        strm.zfree     = Z_NULL;

        if ( inflateInit2( &strm, ( 15 + 32 ) ) != Z_OK )
        {
            NSLog( @"Could not initialise ZLib" );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        while ( done == NO )
        {
            // Make sure we have enough room and reset the lengths.

            if ( strm.total_out >= [ decompressedData length ] )
            {
                [ decompressedData increaseLengthBy: half_length ];
            }

            strm.next_out  = [ decompressedData mutableBytes ] + strm.total_out;
            strm.avail_out = ( unsigned int )( [ decompressedData length ] - strm.total_out );

            // Inflate another chunk.

            status = inflate( &strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH );

            if ( status == Z_STREAM_END )
            {
                done = YES;
            }
            else if ( status != Z_OK )
            {
                NSLog( @"Decompression failed with status %i", status );
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( inflateEnd( &strm ) != Z_OK )
        {
            NSLog( @"Could not complete decompression" );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // Set real length.

        if ( done )
        {
            [ decompressedData setLength: strm.total_out ];

            NSString * string = [ [ NSString alloc ] initWithData: decompressedData
                                                         encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ];

            NSLog( @"String: %@", string );
        }
        else
        {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    NSLog( @"...Success" );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When run, this prints something like:

```
2016-06-16 12:40:14.454 Objective Z[82569:7532295] Starting...
2016-06-16 12:40:14.455 Objective Z[82569:7532295] String: This is input text.
2016-06-16 12:40:14.455 Objective Z[82569:7532295] ...Success
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

You'll need to ensure you link against ZLib. From your project's Build Phases section in XCode, under "Link Binary With Libraries", the "+" button gives a searchable popup; look for "libz". This might not be present on iOS; it is present in the OS X SDK; that's beyond scope of this answer and Google will doubtless present an answer swiftly if you have trouble.